# How to solve $\ddot{x}+\omega^2(t) x-\frac1{x^3}=0$ for a particular form of $\omega$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Suppose we have the following non-linear differential equation

$\ddot{x}+\omega^2(t) x-\frac1{x^3}=0$

with $x(t)$ being a real function (and $\omega(t)$ being also time-dependent).

Is there an analytical solution?

If not, is there an analytical solution for some particular form of $\omega(t)$?

If the answer is again no, what software would be recommendable for numerical solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can make $\omega$ explicit with

$$\omega^2(t)=\frac1{x^4(t)}-\frac{\ddot x(t)}{x(t)},$$ and any analytical function $x(t)$ can do !

Comment: The OP wants $x(t)$ for a particular $\omega$.

Comment: @Paul: that's what I am providing. For example, with $\omega^2=1/t^4$, $x=t$. Or with $\omega^2=e^{-4t}+1$, $x=e^t$. Or with $\omega^2=t-5/(16t^2)$, $x=1/\sqrt[4]t+23$. Is that enough ?

Comment: @ Yves Daoust - yes, the question is a little ambiguous, but I still think the OP knows w(t) and wants a solution process to find x(t), if possible, not the other way round.

Comment: @Paul: the OP wants an $\omega$ for which there is an analytical solution. I am not providing one, but an infinity (admittedly, only a countable infinity).

Comment: Isn't the sign in front of  $\frac{\ddot x(t)}{x(t)}$ wrong? And yes, I know $w(t)$ and want a solution process to find x(t).

Comment: @wondering: yep, the sign is wrong, fixing. The signs also need to be adjusted in my comment to Paul.

Comment: @wondering: I answered the "If not" part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

This ODE has the interesting name of type [Ermakov (Yermakov) equation](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0303.pdf).

And the solving approach is also tricky.

Comment: Are you referring to the solving approach from the link that you posted?